# Django Views file showing tab error when deployed on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-views, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My views.py is working absolutely fine on my local server but when deployed on AWS Beanstalk it's showing this error:

[image]

My views.py file is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from django.shortcuts import render
from models import EmailForm


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})


def sendmail(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message + " from " + email, 'akshat.akshat6@gmail.com', ['akshatuppalweb@gmail.com'])
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            except Exception, e:
                return HttpResponse('Except Block executed.' + str(e))
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Form not Valid")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't mix tabs and spaces in your indentation.
double check spaces in your python files